# MVC - Default Value in Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] BackupSet AccountToCreate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        _DBE.AddToBackupSet(AccountToCreate);
        _DBE.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I need to have the value of User.Identity.Name set to be the value of one of the fields in the create view when I post it to the database.

I am sure its very simple but really don't know how.

Thanks, 
Steve.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to store the username in the view? You will surely be initiating the DB transaction from within a controller so if it's the username for the user that is currently logged in use the MembershipProvider as per the last suggestion:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

If not perhaps you should consider creating a container/wrapper class that clearly represents your View model - some might consider this overkill for one extra property but I hate "magic strings" in code.

```
public class MyView
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public MyObject MyMainObject { get; set;}

    public MyView(string username, MyObject myMainObject)
    {
        this.Username = username;
        this.MyMainObject = myMainObject;
    }
}
```

then set your view model type as:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNamespace.MyView>
```

this then allows you to have strongly typed properties for everything in your view e.g.

```
<%=Model.Username %>
<%=Model.MyMainObject.Title %>
```

and in your controller you can parameterize your Action as

```
public ActionResult(MyMainObject myMainObject, string username)
{
     //Do something here

     //if not correct
     return View(new MyView(username, myMainObject));
}
```

If instead you wanted to go down this path:

```
ViewData["Name"] = User.Identity.Name;
```

or

```
ViewData.Add("Name", User.Identity.Name);
```

Consider creating Enums to once again avoid using string literals e.g.

```
public enum UserEnum
{
   Username,
   Password
}
```

then use:

```
ViewData.Add(UserEnum.Username.ToString(), User.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: OK, I am now on the right page.  The answer is I shouldn't have been doing it in the view.  I have just added AccountToCreate.agency = User.Identity.Name; to my controller code and it now works a treat, sorry it took some time for me to get my head around it, easy when you know how!!

Answer (score 0):

one of the fields in view?

how about simply setting

```
ViewData["Name"] = User.Identity.Name
```

and then in View use it wherever you want.

Comment: Will try and explain a bit more.

Comment: Rob has explained in much more detail in his answer what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Long Answer:

You should probably make a membership service to provide that value. The default MVC2 project will provide IMembershipService interface which you can expand to provide property: CurrentUserName (or whatever you like)

```
public string CurrentUserName
        {
            get
            {
                var context = HttpContext.Current;
                if (null != context)
                    return context.User.Identity.Name;

                var user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
                return (null == user)
                           ? string.Empty
                           : user.Identity.Name;
            }
        }
```